# How to add search box in products and orders page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using multivendor and multimarketplace ecommerce plugin (Docan theme) for my wordpress website. I have separate menu bar for seller like dashboard, product, orders etc. I want to add a search box in product listing when any seller login and click the products menu, it should display a search box to search a product by name or some other fields. I am attaching an image for this so it can be understandable what to do in it.[image: This image contains what i want to do]

[image: This is selled dashboard page]

Comment: You have an excellent free plugin for that purpose: [WooCommerce Order Search](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-order-searching/). I think that this is what you want

Comment: @LoicTheAztec : when i installed this plugin it is showing error like fatal error: call to a member function populate() on a non-object in wp-content/plugins/ in order search file

Comment: Have you try to contact plugin support, or searched through the threads of this support for similar cases?